# Replace dozens of joins with something more efficient to count individually grouped columns

Tags: postgresql

There is a table (in PostgreSQL) with multiple columns (from n1 to n10) each of which contains individual digits in every row (in the example below the digits are 1, 2 and 3 for simplicity purposes). There are thousands of rows in the table. Excerpt of the data in the table:

```
+----+----+----+------+-----+
| n1 | n2 | n3 | n... | n10 |
+----+----+----+------+-----+
|  3 |  2 |  1 |    1 |   1 |
|  2 |  1 |  2 |    2 |   3 |
|  1 |  1 |  2 |    3 |   1 |
|  2 |  3 |  1 |    1 |   2 |
|  3 |  2 |  1 |    1 |   2 |
|  1 |  3 |  1 |    3 |   3 |
|  2 |  3 |  1 |    3 |   3 |
|  1 |  1 |  3 |    3 |   1 |
|  3 |  2 |  3 |    1 |   2 |
|  2 |  1 |  2 |    2 |   1 |
+----+----+----+------+-----+
```

What I'm trying to do is to count individual digits in every column so that the result table looks like this:

```
+--------+----------+----------+----------+------------+-----------+
| number | n1_count | n2_count | n3_count | n..._count | n10_count |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+------------+-----------+
|      1 |        3 |        4 |        5 |          4 |         4 |
|      2 |        4 |        3 |        3 |          2 |         3 |
|      3 |        3 |        3 |        2 |          4 |         3 |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

And I've managed to achieve this by using multiple left joins:

```
SELECT number, n1_count, n2_count, n3_count, n..._count, n10_count FROM
  (VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('3') AS t (number)
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT n1, COUNT(n1) AS n1_count FROM table GROUP BY n1) AS n1_ ON n1 = number
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT n2, COUNT(d2) AS n2_count FROM table GROUP BY n2) AS n2_ ON n2 = number
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT n3, COUNT(d3) AS n3_count FROM table GROUP BY n3) AS n3_ ON n3 = number
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT n..., COUNT(d4) AS n..._count FROM table GROUP BY n...) AS n..._ ON n... = number
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT n10, COUNT(d5) AS n10_count FROM table GROUP BY n10) AS n10_ ON n10 = number;
```

But the final query (10 left joins) looks scary huge and quite complicated so I am wondering if the same result can be achieved via more elegant and efficient way? Please point me to the options I have there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use filtered aggregation and a single join using an array:

```
select t.number, 
       count(*) filter (where tt.n1 = t.number) as n1_count,
       count(*) filter (where tt.n2 = t.number) as n2_count,
       count(*) filter (where tt.n3 = t.number) as n3_count,
       count(*) filter (where tt.n4 = t.number) as n4_count
from the_table tt
  join (values (1),(2),(3) ) as t(number) on t.number = any(array[tt.n1,tt.n2,tt.n3,tt.n4])
group by t.number;
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it's working and I didn't know about this way. But unfortunately the query takes 42 ms to complete, while my initial query does it at 14ms. Even though your solution looks way more neat, it's not that efficient...